# When to use which vs subset function when calculating mean

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, mean

I am trying to make a find the mean of a variable (age) by gender in R. Age and gender are each columns in the a dataset and I want to find the mean of age for women and for men. I believe I need to use the which function, but am unsure how to actually do that and was wondering if using the subset function would make more sense.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(age ~ sex, dat, mean)
#   sex  age
# 1   1 24.5
# 2   2 24.0
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), age = c(28L, 
19L, 26L, 25L, 22L, 27L, 23L), x = c(0.978226428385824, 0.117487361654639, 
0.474997081561014, 0.560332746244967, 0.904031387297437, 0.138710167724639, 
0.988891728920862)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_by(sex) %>%
      summarise(age = mean(age))
```